# Javascript Class Assign Class Function To Button

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class (ES6) and I'm trying to assign a function from that class to a button created by the class. This my main class

```
class tabDrawer {
constructor(bodyID) {
    this.bodyID = bodyID;
    this.tabArray = [];
    this.initialized = false;
}

get getBodyID() {
    return this.bodyID;
}

initialize() {
    this.body = document.getElementById(this.bodyID);
    var baseHTML = "<div id='tabDiv'><div class='tab'></div><div class='tabContentDiv'></div></div>";
    this.body.innerHTML = baseHTML;
    this.initialized = true;
}

addTab(tab) {
    if(this.initialized) {
        var tabClass = "tabLinks";
        if(this.tabArray.length === 0) {
            tabClass += " active";
        }
        console.log(this.tabArray.length);
        this.body.children[0].children[0].innerHTML += "<button class='" + tabClass + "' id='btn" + tab.name + "'>" + tab.tabTitle + "</button>";
        this.body.children[0].children[1].innerHTML += "<div style='display: none' id='" + tab.name + "' class='tabContent'>" + tab.content + "</div>"

        var tabButton = document.getElementById("btn" + tab.name);
        tabButton.addEventListener("click", evt => this.openTab(evt));

        this.tabArray[this.tabArray.length] = tab;
    }
}

openTab(index) {
    var tabByIndex = this.tabArray[index];

    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabLinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(tabByIndex.name).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("btn" + tabByIndex.name).className += " active";
}
}
```

When a tab gets added (as seen in addTab()) the class creates a button in the tabDrawers body and I want to assign the function openTab(index) which is also in the class. I know I can't just add the event listener with "this.openTab" as it will refer to the button instead of the class.

The line `tabButton.addEventListener("click", evt => this.openTab(evt));`seems to work but I'm not sure how to pass the index parameter to the function as I want the function to still be available to the end user as well so they can do this: `tabs.openTab(0);` with "tabs" being an instance of tabDrawer.

Can this be done? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: @Salketer Hmm I thought that didn’t work, it appears to work but it seems like I have another issue that made it seem like It didn’t work so I’m gonna try a few things

Comment: Could you share your html related to the script?

Comment: @user265889 sorry, I delete my comment as it was more appropriate to create a full answer after all

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create HTML elements (not innerHTML) then you can assign [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) to those created elements. Simple as this:

```js
var myClickMeFunction = function() {
    alert('you clicked myClickMeFunction');
};

var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.classList.add('xxx');
    button.textContent = 'Click me';
    
    button.addEventListener('click', myClickMeFunction);
    
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

```css
.xxx {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the index, you should use `this.tabArray.length` instead of `evt` in your event. The problem is that the length will change when adding another tab, so you need to scope it:

```
var self = this;
var handler = function (index){
    return function(){
        self.openTab(index);
    }
}
tabButton.addEventListener("click",handler(this.tabArray.length));
```

This will execute the handler function, to create the event handler using the index from the parameter.

You could do way simpler tough... The only reason you are needing the index is to grab the tab from a tabArray! Why not simply pass the tab directly? This would make it way simpler:

```
tabButton.addEventListener("click",()=>this.openTab(tab));
```